# What type of Reader to use when generating a Private Key in Go?

Tags: go, rsa, private-key

I need to generate a private key in Go. I am using the rsa package (http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/). In particular, it seems that I would like to use the GenerateKey method. One of the parameters for this method is of type io.Reader (http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), but it seems like there are many different types of readers. Is there any advantage to using one type of Reader over another? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that in this particular case the suitable io.Reader would be, for example, [crypto/rand.Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#pkg-variables).

> var Reader io.Reader
>
> Reader is a global, shared instance of a cryptographically strong pseudo-random generator. On Unix-like systems, Reader reads from /dev/urandom. On Windows systems, Reader uses the CryptGenRandom API.